# Why does GCC accept convertion from 'const char *' to 'char *' on std::strrchr() returned value?

Tags: c++, g++, type-conversion, const-char, strrchr

While adding a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16914149/938111), I noticed that GCC does not warn the following code while Visual C++ complains.

```
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    const char CONSTSTR[] = "foo/bar/foobar.txt";

    char *nonconst = std::strrchr (CONSTSTR, '/');
    // cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'

    *nonconst++ = 'B';
    *nonconst++ = 'A';
    *nonconst++ = 'D';
}
```

I have tested three different GCC versions:

- 4.1.2 on Red Hat (Linux)
- 4.5.3 on Cygwin (Windows)
- 4.7.2 on MinGW (Windows)

But all these three GCC versions compiled this code without any warning/error:

```
> g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi test.cpp && echo "success"
success
```

While Microsoft compiler v16 complains:

```
> cl -c test.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(5) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'
        Conversion loses qualifiers
```

(from my office, I do not have access to ideone/codepad/... to test it using other versions)

As this code uses [std::strrchr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strrchr), I do not understand why GCC does not complain.

```
const char* strrchr( const char* str, int ch );  //the code above uses this declaration
      char* strrchr(       char* str, int ch );
```

My question: **Why does g++ successfully compile this code without any warning/error? Is it a bug? a feature? a miss-configuration on my side?**

Comment: Weird... gcc 4.7.2 http://ideone.com/7rcwVE error `error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]` but gcc 4.3.2 http://ideone.com/fDdZ08 no error. Old compiler bug? Could you try with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi file.cpp` (or a subset of these options)?

Comment: So what is the question? Also, my version of GCC (4.6.3) does give the expected error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your g++ does not accept the conversion from '`const char *`' to '`char *`', it's just that on your version `std::strrchr()` returns a `char*` (incorrectly, instead of a `const char*`).

To verify the first part of my statement, try to compile the following on your GCC versions, I predict that all will correctly issue an error:

```
int main()
{
    const char* p = "foo";
    char* q = p;  // error, invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
}
```

Now for the second part, I tried to compile the following minimal code, whose actual aim is to *trigger an error* in order to *list the declared overloads* of `std::strrchr`:

```
#include <cstring>
void (*p)() = &std::strrchr;  // error here, with "candidates are: ..."
int main() {}
```

Well, with [gcc 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/lybnei) the message shows the expected "all non-const" and "all const" overloads:

```
prog.cpp:2:21: error: no matches converting function ‘strrchr’ to type ‘void (*)()’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/cstring:44:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/string.h:249:1: error: candidates are: char* strrchr(char*, int)
/usr/include/string.h:255:1: error:                 const char* strrchr(const char*, int)
```

i.e. the prototypes

```
      char* strrchr(       char* , int );
const char* strrchr( const char* , int );  // Question's code will use this one (-> error)
```

But with [gcc 4.3.2](http://ideone.com/bzWXC0) the message was different:

```
prog.cpp:2: error: no matches converting function 'strrchr' to type 'void (*)()'
/usr/include/string.h:171: error: candidates are: char* strrchr(const char*, int)
/usr/include/c++/4.3/cstring:118: error:                 char* std::strrchr(char*, int)
```

i.e. the overloads were

```
      char* strrchr( const char* , int );  // Question's code would use this one (-> no error...)
      char* strrchr(       char* , int );
```

(the second one is the C++ non-const overload; but the first one is the old *C version*, and should instead be the C++ const overload).

This it seems that the headers (`<cstring>` and/or `<string.h>`) were incorrect on this version, and I suspect that it's the same on yours.

---

Edit: I found for example a [discussion](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2006-02/msg00086.html), a [blog post](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/07/how-not-to-fix-gcc-4-4-bugs) and a [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49020) (for `strchr` not `strrchr` but it's the same story).

Comment: Perfect ;-) Very very good answer. Thank you for all your details, every thing is clear now :-D Cheers