# How come C standard library function `strchr` returns pointer to non-const, when given `const char *` as first argument?

Tags: c, gcc, constants, strchr

Compilation of given code sample with gcc/g++ succeeds. There is no error for `strchr` call, which obviously assignes `const char *` to `char *`.

I've found `strchr` is declared as `char * strchr(const char *, int)` on two different sources [pubs.opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strchr.html) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/)

If `strchr` is implemented as to cast away constness, then why's that so?

If goal was to provide function which works both on `char *` and `const char *` strings - it could have been implemented using two different function names.

Can you give more thorough explanation on this.

```
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    const char *str = "Sample string";
    char * ptr;

    //ptr = str;            //  Error: discards const qualifier - both on gcc and g++
    pch = strchr(str,'S');  //  Succeeds in assigning <const char *> to <char *>

    *pch = '4';             //  Runtime error: segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

Tried it on Win7 using MSYS2/mingw-w64 gcc_v5.3.0 and TDM-gcc32 v5.1.0 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does strchr implementation work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367727/how-does-strchr-implementation-work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `strchr` with a `char*` you want a `char*` back, so that you don't need to do a cast on the result. C doesn't support function overloading, so the same `strchr` function is used for searching in a `char*` and in a `const char*`. It returns a non-const pointer in all cases. If you call it with a `const char*` it is basically casting away the `const` so it is the callers responsibility to use it safely (e.g. by assigning the result to a `const char*` immediately, to avoid any unsafe use of the returned pointer).

> If goal was to provide function which works both on char * and const char * strings - it could have been implemented using two different function names.

Yes, it could have been, but it isn't done like that. The original version of C didn't support `const` at all, so it was always the programmer's responsibility to avoid trying to modify string literals. If different function names were used then it would have broken existing code that used `strchr` safely. It would have slowed the adoption of the new `const` keyword if traditional C code like this suddenly stopped compiling:

```
char arr[] = "foo bar";
*strchr(arr, 'r') = 'z';
```

The "spirit of C" is that it doesn't try to stop you doing unsafe things, it's your job to write correct code.

In C++ `strchr` is overloaded to preserve constness:

```
char* strchr(char*, int);
const char* strchr(const char*, int);
```

This means it automatically does the right thing, and it's much harder to accidentally write unsafe code with `strchr`.