# C array of values, pointer segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, pointers, max

In my `main()` function I create an array, find the address of the highest value and increase the value at the address:

```
int main()
{
    int i[5] = {2,5,6,5,3};
    int *pi = getAdres(i);
    (*pi)++;

    printf("%d", i[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The `getAdres()` function looks like:

```
int getAdres(int *i)
{
    int *pi;
    int higest = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if(i[j] > higest)
        {
            pi = &i[j];
            higest = i[j];
        }
    }
    return pi;
}
```

Without making the get address part into a function it works but in the current format `(*pi)++;` is giving me a segmentation fault. 
What is going wrong?

Comment: What is `if(i[j] > higest)` is never true? what are you returning then?

Comment: Also, note the compiler warnings!!!

Comment: Your function returns an `int` whereas it should actually return `int*`. hat probably happens is that `int*` gets truncated into `int` and thus causing segfault.

Comment: @usr that's the thing!! A(ny) decent compiler should warn about the mismatch here, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `getAdres` has the return type `int` instead of `int *`.

```
int getAdres(int *i)
^^^
```

But in any case its implementation is bad. It uses magic number 5 and moreover an arbitrary array passed to the function can have for example only negative values.

The function definition for example can look like

```
int * getMaxElement( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    size_t highest = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[highest] < a[i] )
        {
            highest = i;
        }
    }

    return ( int * )a + highest;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
int *pi = getMaxElement( i, sizeof( i ) / sizeof( *i ) );
++*pi;

printf( "%d\n", *pi );
```

Comment: Fixed a small bug. `0` -> `a[0]`

Comment: @klutt You did not fixed a bug. You inserted a bug.

Comment: I realize that now. Misread your code. Sorry.

Comment: Dropping `const` like that is quite strange in my opinion. Better to return a `const` pointer, and have the caller cast it away (the caller knows that it's going to write, and also owns the array).

Comment: Or just remove const... because here that don't make any sense. cast that break const is... really a bad practice to teach.

Comment: @unwind Now you will know how such functions should be written in C.:) Also consider for example the standard C function strchr.

Comment: @Stargateur It is a good function implementation that satisfies the C Standard convention about such functions.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think that's very strange reasoning, and that `strchr()` looks like that for two reasons: history, and string literals. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842263/how-come-c-standard-library-function-strchr-returns-pointer-to-non-const-when). I'm certainly not willing to consider it a good design in general.

Comment: @unwind There is no function overloading in C. So it is a general approach to define functions such a way for constant and non-constant arrays. There is no need casting for a constant pointer and a non-constant pointer to accept the result. Otherwise your code will be overloaded with numerous castings that makes it difficult to read. So the implementation of the function I showed is the best implementation.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I never said it wasn't a "good function implementation" but clearly a broken design function. There no way this should be considerate as a good practice, standard C library is obviously not perfect and this one is a great example of bad practice (and stupidity). You want two behaviors ? Do two functions.

Comment: @Stargateur Well you can make a proposal to the C Standard Committee to double almost all C string function declarations.:) By the way the function themselves have one and only one behavior. It is the client of the functions that have a choice.:)

Comment: @Stargateur And moreover it is a bad practice and as you said stupidity to write the same algorithm twice in two different places and having different names for the same algorithm.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Let the caller of this function handle the cast would be mush more clean practice, but still prefer two function. This algorithm could be write in a macro that take a type `int *` or `int const *` and you will not write twice the same algorithm. I think committee are very aware of this problem but there don't want breaking change.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong return type, make it:

```
int * getAddressToMax(int *i);
```

Also make sure it does in fact return a valid pointer. If the entire array is 0, it will return an uninitialized pointer which is a really bad idea. Make it:

```
int *pi = i;
```

to make it return a pointer to the first element, in that case.

Also you commonly see:

```
int highest = i[0];
```

and then starting the loop from `1`, for cases like this. Passing the length of the array is also very common in real code, hardcoding that kind of knowledge inside what could be a generic function makes things harder to understand (and kills code re-use, of course).

Comment: @4386427 Good point, edited.